# about rails' routes, adding collection routes to restful resources won't generate named route helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, resources, routes

---

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :posts do
        collection do
            get 'whatever'
        end
    end
end
```

---

I was expect that will generate 'whatever_admin_posts_path' helper method, but it didn't.
It's there something wrong with my codes? Or a bug in rails?

Answer (score 1):

The namespace isn't typically added to the method that returns the route. So you probably have a route `whatever_posts_path`. The rake task `rake routes` is particularly useful in these cases. The first part of the display for each route is the name of the method you can use to access it (if available).